# Optimize and host images in Azure?

Tags: image, azure, web, hosting

I'd like to host images for my website on Azure. The images should be compressed and available in different resolutions.

Of course, I could just compress and scale the images by myself and put them in a blob storage.

But is there a way to let Azure do the work for me?
I want to upload an image in a very high resolution and Azure should create versions in different resolutions and compress them. After that the image should be published so that I can retrieve it from my website.

Is there a better way to host images than Azure blob storage?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Azure function with blob trigger to do it, I have posted a solution here before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66251887/pil-unidentifiedimageerror-from-azure-blob-trigger-though-image-opens-in-watch/66253773#66253773 . let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Event Subscription that will respond to the **blob storage uploaded** event, after that, an Azure Function will be triggered and will handle the event by creating a resized version of an image and copying it to a separate storage container. This is an auto-scale solution. An example that exactly describes your situation can be found on official microsoft docs page [Tutorial: Automate resizing uploaded images using Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event).

> Event Grid enables Azure Functions to respond to Azure Blob storage events and generate thumbnails of uploaded images. An event subscription is created against the Blob storage create event. When a blob is added to a specific Blob storage container, a function endpoint is called. Data passed to the function binding from Event Grid is used to access the blob and generate the thumbnail image.